# Xpath works in Chorome but not in Selenium web-driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working on a website where all other locator doesn't work expect using FindElements and take the 3rd a element. So I was curious to try xpath the first time.

I could get the xpath in chrome, but when I use in xpath, it says element not found.

I did a lot of search, still couldn't' find out what was wrong. So I tried in facebook page and use the login field as a try, the xpath is //*[@id="email"], it works perfectly in chrome, but same result in webdrive.

C# code: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']"));

[Please click for facebook picture and its location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t22SR.png)
Any advise?

Comment: Can you please share the text form html of the element.

Comment: It is the main facebook page without login. https://www.facebook.com/

Comment: Are you getting `no such element` exception when tried with that xpath?

Comment: It's most likely a wait problem that requires an explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

I can give a complete solution on Python taking into account the features of React Native (used on Facebook)

But, you have C#. Therefore, it is possible to use a similar function **driver.execute_script** (execution of Javascript on Selenium)

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.execute_script('
      document.getElementById("email").value = "lg@hosct.com";
      document.getElementById("u_0_2").click();
')
```

Comment: GetElementById works, I already know that, just curous on how xpath work. I get it to work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did another try with a more clear code:

driver.Url = "";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']"));

It works now, the only difference between this and my code before is: I was visiting some other pages before the facebook page. This seems to make difference. Anyway, above code works. If I encounter the issue again, I will post more detail code.